# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have an input data(X_train) with data shape (180,11,161)
180-> no. of subjects   11->no. of electrodes   161->no. of samples

I used the following code for the input layer:

```
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input shape=(180,11,161)))
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

What's the mistake? If Conv2D shouldn't be used, what else should I use?Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please don't ask "What's the mistake?" questions again. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @fuuman I have altered the question

Comment: did you find solution?